# How to add list of objects class to arraylist?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Need to add list of objects with errors to an arraylist body.
code where I'm trying to set `response.getErrors()` to `response.getBody()`:

```
String jsonResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestBody, String.class);
JavaType valueType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(ResponseContainer.class, type);
ResponseContainer<ResponseType> response = mapper.readValue(jsonResponse, valueType);
        // TODO if error != null put errors to body
if (response.getErrors() != null) {
    response.getBody().addAll(response.getErrors());
}
return response.getBody();
```

Model class:

```
@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Список параметров сообщения")
List<T> body = new ArrayList<T>();

@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Список ошибок")
List<ResponseError> errors;
```

Error is:

```
Error:(70, 35) java: no suitable method found for add(java.util.List<com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError>)
method java.util.Collection.add(ResponseType) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.List<com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError> cannot be converted to ResponseType)
method java.util.List.add(ResponseType) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.List<com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError> cannot be converted to ResponseType)
```

Comment: Is that really the full error message?

Comment: Yes, full error is in response.getErrors()

Comment: No I meant is "in List cannot be applied" the full error message?

Comment: ohhh, i'm sorry. Error is: addAll (java.util.Collection<? extends ResponseType>) in List cannot be applied to (java.util.List<com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError>)

Comment: It looks like com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError does not inherit from ResponseType. If both list are part of the ´`response` object why do you need to join them at all?

Comment: @ChingizBatirbaev please, show what `com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError ` looks like and include the detailed  erro message in the question

Comment: @ChingizBatirbaev - What happens if you change `ResponseContainer<ResponseType> response` to `ResponseContainer<ResponseError> response` ?

Comment: Also @ChingizBatirbaev  - please update the error message (at least 5 to 6 lines) stack thread

Comment: ResponseError looks like this: @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Источник ошибки")
    String source;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Код ошибки")
    String code;

Comment: i can't change type of response to responseError because it's an integration with 3d party services.

Comment: Error:(70, 35) java: no suitable method found for addAll(java.util.List<com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError>)
    method java.util.Collection.addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends ResponseType>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.List<com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<? extends ResponseType>)
    method java.util.List.addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends ResponseType>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch;

Comment: java.util.List<com.infin.it.integrator.impl.base.ResponseError> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<? extends ResponseType>)

Comment: @smilyface please help me

Comment: @ChingizBatirbaev - First of all, we are here to help. Please update the errors you mentioned in your question properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442753/a-required-class-was-missing-while-executing-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-war keep this as an example - see how he has provided details of exception he got.

Comment: another example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280705/spring-boot-admin-server-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed type of `@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Список ошибок")
List<ResponseError> errors;` to `List<T> errors = new ArrayList<T>();`
Soon i added fields that came from response to my `ResponseBaseModel.class`, to take that fields and show an error.

That's solved my problem. Thanks for all to advices.